# Android VideoView - Possible to Colorize/Add Tint to MP4 while video is playing?

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to colorize/add tint to a VideoView while an MP4 is playing. For example, a blue tint should be added and the video will remain visible while playing. Is this possible?

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could overlay a view with a drawable on to the video using a framelayout. You could set the background of the view on top of the video to something with an alpha channel from there. Something like:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <VideoView
         android:id="@+id/myVideo"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <View 
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/semi_transparent_blue"/>
<FrameLayout/>
```

Comment: Thanks...I tried "@color/semi_transparent_blue", which didn't work, but using a hex code with alpha pair worked. I'm using Xamarin, so not sure if that's the difference.

Comment: I spoke too soon on this solution. Although it works on my physical phone, I tested on several emulated devices and the alpha setting doesn't work (just shows solid color). Is this due to differences in API?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears to be an issue specific to Android emulators. I installed the same Android API version on an old phone and the alpha worked as expected.